# Python: strftime, gmtime not respecting timezone

Tags: python, timezone

```
import time
print time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %I:%M %p %Z", time.gmtime())
```

I live in California. For some reason, this code is reporting the time in GMT, instead of respecting the system time zone. I know that strftime knows I'm in pacific, because it still prints 'PST' at the end, but it's still 8 hours ahead. Is anyone else noticing this? Anyone know what's either wrong with my system or my code?

**EDIT**:
running `date` at the command line gives me the correct date. Additionally, I've run this on two different computers (mac and linux) and they both report 8 hours ahead. Are you expected to correct for timezone before using strftime?

Comment: What if you just run "date" on the command line? Could it be that your computer's time is set to GMT, but has a California timezone?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[`time.gmtime()`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.gmtime) returns the time in UTC. What you need is [`time.localtime()`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.localtime), which *is* timezone-aware. This behaviour is well-documented in the [`time` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html).

EDIT:

To convert any `time.time()` style timestamp to a `struct_time`, you can supply an argument to 
[`time.localtime()`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.localtime):

```
>>> print time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %I:%M:%S %p %Z", time.localtime(10.5))
Thu, 01 Jan 1970 02:00:10 AM EET
```

Comment: time.localtime() is great, but I'm getting my timestamp from a file in UTC.  How do I convert a timezone from UTC to my local timezone?

Comment: @Shaun: You may find [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) useful for more involved timezone conversions.  `time.localtime` has some issues when working with timestamps not around now (e.g. in the past or future beyond a daylight savings change, etc.).

Comment: Just if anybody else wonders: `10.5` is just the time 10.5s after epoch. Usually there would stand something like `time.time()` or `1596618141`.

Answer (score 1):

To change the timezone on your unix system, do something like this:

```
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles /etc/localtime
```

Browse around in `/usr/share/zoneinfo/` to find what you want and alter the command above

Comment: Not my downvote, but this seems like an answer to a quite different question.